# How do I change the JNI method signature in the so file?

Tags: java

How do I change the JNI method signature in the so file?
That is, how to modify dynamic symbol table, I tried using the hex editing tool to replace the string inside, but the prompt could not find the implemented function

The reverse engineering need, I need to modify the JNI Java_com_tencent_mm forced Java_com_tencent_mn SmalI has been modified successfully, but the so file to replace Java_com_tencent_mm Java

I've noticed that a app has implemented this requirement, but I don't know how he did it

Comment: You'd have to modify the source and recompile it to a new .so.  You can't modify the byte code in the .so.

Comment: I found someone who has successfully modified and worked properly. I really want to master this technique, but thank you for your answer